# How to extract columnes from Python list?

Tags: python, list, operators

My Python code

```
import operator

with open('index.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

print type(lines)
print len(lines)

l2=lines[1::3] 
print len(l2)
print l2[0]

list1 = [0,2]
my_items = operator.itemgetter(*list1)
new_list = [ my_items(x) for x in l2 ]

with open('newindex1.txt','w') as thefile:
    for item in l2:
        thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Couple of lines from `index.txt`

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 2 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
3 0 0
```

Couple of lines from `newindex1.txt`

```
0 1 0
1 1 0
2 1 0
3 1 0
4 1 0
5 1 0
6 1 0
7 1 0
8 1 0
9 1 0
```

I wanted to read the file as a list,then choose every third row and then finally select first and the third column from that list.It seems that I do not understand how operator works.

If I try with Back2Basics solution
import numpy as np

myarray = np.fromfile('index.txt', dtype=int, sep=' ')
anotherarray = myarray[::3][0,2]

I got

```
  File "a12.py", line 4, in <module>
    anotherarray = myarray[::3][0,2]
IndexError: too many indices
```

Comment: What mean first in the third column? All elements in your third column in index.txt equal zero..

Comment: @cmashinho First and the third. No they are not all zero,it is just frst 10 lines.

Comment: What do you want from the first text file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham First and the third column,every third row.

Comment: Yeah I had to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read all the data into memory at all, you can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to parse the rows you want and the [csv lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read and write the data:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice
import  csv

with open("in.txt") as f, open('newindex1.txt','w') as out:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    wr = csv.writer(out, delimiter=" ")
    for row in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, 0, 3, 3)), []):
        wr.writerow(map(itemgetter(0, 2), row)[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly suggest using numpy for this.  The reason being this is all numerical data that fits so nicely into memory.  The code looks like this.

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.fromfile('index.txt', dtype=int, sep=' ')
anotherarray = myarray[::3,::2]
```

and then you want to write the file

```
anotherarray.tofile('newfile.txt', sep=" ")
```

The way the array slicing line `[::3,::2]` reads is "take every 3rd row starting from 0, and take every other column starting from 0"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something this?

```
lines = []

with open('index.txt', 'r') as fi:
    lines = fi.read().splitlines()

lines = [line.split() for line in lines]

with open('answer.txt', 'w') as fo:
    for column in range(len(lines)):
        if (column + 1) % 3:
            fo.write('%s %s\n' % (lines[column][0], lines[column][2]))
```